# How to copy an Apache installation

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I've got an Apache installation that I'd like to replicate on another server. I don't have any of the source files so I don't know what `configure` options it was built with. I know what modules are installed from `httpd - V` but don't know how to translate that to the `configure` and `make` steps.

I'm running on Centos 7 and will be managing it with `systemctl`, in case that makes a difference!

Comment: Has it even been compiled from source? It's not good practice to do so. You should use the packaged version instead.

Comment: The packaged version from the Red Hat repositories is 2.4.6, which is several years old now. I'd rather compile it myself than rely on a 3rd party repo.

Comment: That version is patched with all security patches until CentOS 7 hits it's end of life. If you need newer features, use CentOS 8 or go with Rocky Linux. Personally, I wouldn't want to have to recompile everything every time a new version is released.

Comment: just compile the same version on the new system abd copy /etc/apache2 and /var/www  and you can duplicate your setup as often as you want. (the pathes are used on debian i am unfamiliar with centos but it should worjthe same way)

Comment: @djdomi How can I compile the same version on the new system? I don't know what options the old version was compiled with.